# Python 3.X using multiple *args for different stuff

Tags: python, function, args, keyword-argument

I know that *args are used when you dunno how many args are being used inside the function call. However, what do I do when I want one group of  *args to do X and one group of *args to do y?

Comment: You can't. There's only one set of *args per function.

Comment: can you expound? is it your function, what are you trying to do? what's 'one group of args'-a certain number or a certain time or something else?

Comment: group the args into two groups either before or after the function call.

Comment: There are a few ways to do function calls. The two ways to define parameter-requirmenets off functions looks like this `def x(*args, **kwargs)` or `def x(x, y=None)`. And some example calls to functions can look like this: `x(1,2)`, `x(1, y=2)` or `x(1, *{y : 2}). Not sure what you need really..

Comment: `*args` is used when you want all arguments reduced to a single list. If you want one group of args to do X and one to do Y, then you presumably don't want all of your arguments reduced to a single list, therefore you do not want to use `*args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass two `*args` within the single function. You need to pass `args1` and `args2` as plain `list` and you may pass these *lists* as *args* to the functions doing `X` and `Y`. For example:

```
def do_X(*args):
    # Do something

def do_Y(*args):
    # Do some more thing

def my_function(list1, list2):
    do_X(*list1)  # Pass list as `*args` here
    do_Y(*list2)
```

And your call to `my_function` would be like:

```
args_1 = ['x1', 'x2']  # Group of arguments for doing `X`
args_2 = ['y1', 'y2']  # Group of arguments for doing `Y`

# Call your function
my_function(args_1, args_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you take the arguments as two separate lists, which can default to an empty list or None.